# Ratchet PHP: How to mention host name?

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

As per code I did this:

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    8080
);
```

I want to keep host configurable as I'd need to pass that value to JS client as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the code that you provided above then the host is always set to whatever your server is linked to.

If example.com links to your port 80
then example.com:8008 will link to your port 8080 on the server

If you would like to force a client to use a certain host name then that should be done from the subscribe function in your socket itself.

And if you don't have a DNS name and only have an IP address : 123.123.123.123
then 123.123.123.123:8080 will link to your websocket.

please let me know if this is what you asked or if you need further information.